# mxgraph htmltable as a cell label

Tags: javascript, graphics, mxgraph

I try to play with **mxgraph**'s *htmllabel* example and want to use html **table** container as a label for the single created cell. I set table element's 'width' attribute to 100%. But real size of the table is not set to full evailable width of its parent container (cell) and always less it. Can anybody help me to resolve this task?

Thanks in advance